# Can a Wallet be used with SQL Developer? How?

Tags: oracle, wallet, oracle-11g-r2

I have a Wallet configured and working fine for SQLPlus. Is there a way to make it work with SQL Developer?

Comment: This is a feature request on OTN if you would like to vote for it.  http://htmldb.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=42626:39:1601375098170147::NO::P39_ID:23601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to specify an Advanced Connection Type and enter a custom JDBC URL as follows:

jdbc:oracle:oci:/@myDatabase

In addition the "OS Authentication" check box needs to be checked. This would seem to cause it to pass the OS username and password, but apparently (perhaps because I don't have NTS set as an authentication service in my sqlnet.ora) it does not and instead uses the wallet.